# Adding column to serializer whichi is not the member of database table

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a `model` and a `serializer` with `restframework`

This is the `model`

```
class Drawing(models.Model):
    detail = models.JSONField(default=dict,null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)    
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

and `serializer`.

```
class DrawingSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    detail = serializers.JSONField(allow_null=True)
    s3_url = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = m.Drawing
        fields = ('id','detail','s3_url','created_at','updated_at')
```

In `serializer`, it has `s3_url` column, but it is not in the `model`.

So, I want to make `s3_url` for each objects and return like this below.

This is not correct code but shows what I want to do.

calculate `s3_url` from `detail` for each rows of objects.

```
class DrawingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = m.Drawing.objects.all()
    serializer_class = s.DrawingSerializer
    def list(self, request):
        
        queryset = m.Drawing.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by("-id")
        for each in queryset:
            each['s3_url'] = detailToUrl(each['detail'])
        serializer = s.DrawingSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

return json shuold be

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "detail": {'test':1}
        "s3_url": "http://test1/"
     },{
        "id": 2,
        "detail": {'test':2}
        "s3_url": "http://test2/"
     }
]
```

How can I make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic to format the each serialization should be inside the serialization logic.

```
class DrawingSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    detail = serializers.JSONField(allow_null=True)
    s3_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField('_get_url')
    
    class Meta:
        model = m.Drawing
        fields = ('id','detail','s3_url')
    
    def _get_url(self, instance):
        return detailToUrl(self.instance.detail)
```

And then in the viewset simply as:

```
class DrawingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = m.Drawing.objects.all()
    serializer_class = s.DrawingSerializer
```

Hope this can help you

Answer (score 1):

To show the URL representation in a GET request as in your example, you can custom the `s3_url` field on the serializer method `to_representation`. Override the `to_representation` method to support serialization for read operations. Take a look at https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior.

```py
class DrawingSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    detail = serializers.JSONField(allow_null=True)
    s3_url = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = m.Drawing
        fields = ('id','detail','s3_url','created_at','updated_at')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        ret["s3_url"] = detailToUrl(ret["s3_url"])
        return ret
```